# Contact form e-mail validation

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form

I am creating a website and my one functionality, the contact form, needs to be tweaked one last bit to be really successful. I am able to send email via SMTP thanks to an amazing video on youtube. But another tutorial (by the same uploader) had showed how to validate e-mail addresses and I have the code, but when I have it along with my index.php file, it does not seem to work.

By does not seem to work, I mean that the validations do not show up after clicking submit (which is what is supposed to happen according to the video.) I need assistance in knowing where to place the FILTER_VALIDATE php bit in this code, in my index.php.

I am not sure if github links are popular here but here's my github,

https://github.com/orangelimester/Project3.git

and those are the files for the contact form I'm talking about. It sends e-mail no problem (as seen with the thanks screen following it.)

Below is the html of the contact form : index.php

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once 'security.php';
$errors = isset($_SESSION['errors']) ? $_SESSION['errors'] : [];
$fields = isset($_SESSION['fields']) ? $_SESSION['fields'] : [];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable = no">
    <title>Contact</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container alt3">
            <div class="page-header" id="contact">
                <h2>Contact us<small> Contact us for more!</small></h2>
            </div><!--end page header-->
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                <?php if(!empty($errors)): ?>
                    <div class = "panel">
                        <ul>
                            <li> <?php echo implode('</li><li>', $errors); ?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php 
            if (isset($_POST['email']) == true && empty($_POST['email']) == false) {
              $email = $_POST['email'];
                if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == true) {
                echo 'That\'s a valid email address';
                } else {
                echo 'Not a valid email address';
                }
            }
            ?>
                <form action="contact.php" class="form-horizontal"  method="post">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for ="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                    Name</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="text" name = "name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" <?php echo isset($fields['name']) ? 'value ="' . e($fields['name']). '"' : '' ?>>
                    </div>

                 </div><!--end form-group-->

                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="col-lg-2 control-label"> Email</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="text" name = "email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email Address" <?php echo isset($fields['email']) ? 'value ="' . e($fields['email']). '"' : '' ?>>
                    </div>

                 </div><!--end form-group-->


                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message" class="col-lg-2 control-label"> Any message</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" 
                        cols="20" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your Message"><?php echo isset($fields['message']) ? e($fields['message']). '"' : '' ?></textarea>
                    </div>
                 </div><!--end form-group-->

                 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
unset($_SESSION['errors']);
?>
```

Below here is the contact.php, which works just fine!

It's the "FILTER_VALIDATE" php bit in index.php I believe that is not working. In his video tutorial, it's supposed to show up with whether e-mail addresses are valid or not as it is being submitted, but in my case it simply keeps sending the e-mail regardless.

Please do help.

Thank you. As it is evident, I am new to php, I am simply doing this for an important event coming up and for advertising purposes for the future and several questions on here are hard to understand because either they don't answer my question, or the question itself is an entirely different code that I don't need for this basic contact form.

Comment: What **exactl**y not working?

Comment: E-mail validation does not seem to work. If I type abc@gmail , without the .com, it still ends up sending the email.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the ending `</from>` tag is missing.

Comment: That is actually there. When I copy pasted my code here I missed it as I had to crop out a lot of code from the main website. Sorry about that!

Answer (score -1):

Your `form` action tag points to `contact.php` file.

You should validate email **there** and not on `index.php` page.

So, here you have

```
if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message'])) {
    // right now check the email. If it's ok - keep on, if not add to $errors some message
```

Comment: So the php with the FILTER_VALIDATE should be in contact.php? Are you able to see it in my github and tell where ?

Comment: Even with that line there, it still doesn't work for some reason. I just typed "abc@abertw.com" it still ends up sending the e-mail.

Comment: `abc@abertw.com` is normal email. Either your logic in file is invalid.

Comment: So is that it? Will this cause issues in future when the website is up, such as spam or injection attacks? I did include a security.php file to prevent javascript injections.

Comment: `So is that it?` What do you mean? By the way - you'd better now change passwords to your gmail(

Comment: I mean, that is that all the validation I require for e-mail addresses?

Comment: Validation checks correctness of email - it means format, presence of allowed symbols. If you want something else - tell what.